# Small numbers are being rounded off in python

Tags: python, numpy, precision

I want to do calculation on timescales of nanoseconds.

```
>>> N=10
>>> A=10
>>> t = np.linspace(0,A*1e-9,N)
array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.00000001, 0.00000001, 0.00000001, 0.00000001, 0.00000001])
```

But the array is being rounded off, how can I keep the desired precision of

```
A*1e-9/N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running your code on my machine I get:

```
[0.00000000e+00 1.11111111e-09 2.22222222e-09 3.33333333e-09
 4.44444444e-09 5.55555556e-09 6.66666667e-09 7.77777778e-09
 8.88888889e-09 1.00000000e-08]
```

The problem is with your print options, it seems to not use scientific notation. See [this page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) in the manual on how to change that.

In short, your code is fine, your printing of numpy arrays are probably not optimal for your use case.